# Iterate through vector

Tags: matlab, indexing

I wrote this (`column`, `row` and `value` are vectors):

```
for k = column
    for l = row ((column == k) & (row > k))
        A_lk = value (row == l & column == k);
```

The problem is that `k` and `l` are vectors so I can't write `row == l` or `column == k` (I want those `i` for which `row (i)` is `l` and `column (i)` is `k`).

The exact error is: "`mx_el_eq: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 46x1, op2 is 13x1)`".

How can I use all elements in column and row `((column == k) & (row > k))` one by one?

I thought about something like:

```
for i = 1:length(column)
    k = column (i)
```

Is there any other possibility?

**EDIT:**

As I said, I have a sparse matrix (n, n). I have to iterate through all columns and for each column (say, k) I have to iterate through the lines from k+1 to n and do something with the non-zero elements.

Example:

```
row    = [1 3 3 2 1 2]      % row > 2 is [0 1 1 0 0 0] 
column = [1 1 2 2 2 3]  % column == 2 is [0 0 1 1 1 0]  
value  = [8 7 9 5 6 7]  %(column == 2) & (row > 2) is [0 0 1 0 0 0]
```

`row ((column == 2) & (row > 2))` is 3
`value (row == 3 & column == 2)` is 9

What I want the code to do:

```
k in {1, 2, 3}  %writing this I realized I did some useless operations, 
                %since I want just the distinct values of column
k = 1:  
    l in row ((column == 1) & (row > 1)) = {3}  
        l = 3:
            A_31 = value (row == 3 & column == 1) = 7
            %rest of the code
k = 2:
    l in row ((column == 2) & (row > 2)) = {3}
        l = 3
            A_32 = value (row == 3 & column == 2) = 9
            %rest of the code
k = 3:
    l in row ((column == 3) & (row > 3)) = nothing
```

Comment: The `for i = 1:length(column), k = column (i)` seems good coding

Comment: Yes, I know it does what I want, but seems a bit unnatural for MATLAB.

Comment: It seems quite natural for me, but let's wait for other SO users to give their opinion..

Comment: `column` `row` and `value` are all of same lengths?

Comment: Yes. It's a sparse matrix.

Comment: Use some sample values and tell us the expected values in the output `A_lk`, because as your codes stand now, are very confusing.

Comment: @Divakar I added an example.

Comment: Would `M = sparse(row,column,value);` followed by normal matrix operations be considered cheating?

Comment: @Notlikethat Yes; @Divakar The `value` vector contains all non-zero elements. Uhm, not really, `value (column == k & row == l)` is always a number.

Comment: @nowembery The final output would be in different variables named `A_31`, `A_32`, etc. and those will be done separately?

Comment: @Divakar Not necessary, I named them A_lk for clarity. I just use the value to change some other values and then I don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the values of `match_value` in the code below and see if you could use them -

```
row    = [1 3 3 2 1 2]      % row > 2 is [0 1 1 0 0 0] 
column = [1 1 2 2 2 3]  % column == 2 is [0 0 1 1 1 0]
value  = [8 7 9 5 6 7]

k_vector = 1:numel(column)
match_ind = bsxfun(@gt,row,k_vector') & bsxfun(@eq,column,k_vector')
match_value = bsxfun(@times,match_ind,value)
```

Output for `match_value`

```
match_value =

     0     7     0     0     0     0
     0     0     9     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

If you intend to use sparse for the output, you can do so pretty easily like this -

```
>> sparse(match_value)

ans =

   (1,2)        7
   (2,3)        9
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over the columns is straightforward with the help of `unique` - we can easily pull out the nonzero elements of the lower triangular part of each column like this:

```
% this relies on 'row' and 'column' both being row vectors
for c = unique(column)
    colidx = (column == c);
    lowertri = (row > c) & colidx;
    v = value(lowertri);
    % do something with v
end
```

If the row indices of the elements of `v` are also important (rather than just iterating over the values themselves), either use `row(row>c)` in parallel, or just have an inner loop over the rows in the same fashion as the columns.